# How do I get Chrome to un-minimized when activating an existing or opening a new tab?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

I have 18.04 installed with default Gnome desktop. When Chrome is minimized and I click on a link in terminal or via my IDE, Chrome opens a new tab for the link but stays minimized. When this first happened I kept clicking and opening new tabs in the minimized window. I see the same problem if I try to open a tab from task manager or tab management extensions. In all cases, the window stays minimized and doesn't open as I'd expect. What's going on here and how do I fix this behavior? I searched and searched and was unable to find this reported anywhere.

Comment: Your browser may have retained it's last size, which in your case was propably minimized. I suggest you open it and enlarge its size. The normal behavior is that it opens next time with the latest size.

Comment: That is probably how Gnome Shell is designed: the user is in charge of window placement and organization. Accordingly, if you minimize a window, the window will remain minimized. It is up to yourself to bring it back to the foreground. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, installing this Gnome extensions resolved the problem and improved alt-tab navitation: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/